# Change VLC recording format

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I'm using VLC 2.0.2 to stream videos from YouTube and I'm hitting the "Record" button at times so I can store the more interesting parts of the stream on my PC. I was using this just yesterday and it was saving the clips as **.mp4** files, which was great. I just started using it again today, and it's now saving them as **.avi**. This would be fine, but for some reason the playback is messed up (the timing is all off) and there's *no audio*. I'm only doing this for the audio, so that's important.

How can I tell VLC I want to record the current playback as **.mp4**?

Comment: I just tried it and it would use AVI for YouTube video as well, with no audio. Can you verify if this works with all YouTube clips or just certain ones? Are you sure you haven't updated VLC in between? Might want to file a bug report if you were able to do recordings before.

Comment: Isn't VLC saves streams at whatever format stream is served? Did you tried changing extension of file? Tried another player? I also suggest using some media information software aganist files that have problems during playback.

Comment: It seems something has changed. I opened a random video from YouTube and recorded a bit and it was saved as __.avi__. Then I opened the exact video I used yesterday that produced the .mp4 clip. When I streamed and recorded with this one, it saved as .avi also. So, it appears that the format of the uploaded video doesn't matter (if the uploaded video was .mp4 then the test would have worked today).

Comment: I've also tried downgrading to v2.0.0 and the last v1 release (something like v1.1.9) available on Videolan's ftp server. 2.0.0 had the same issues, and the v1 was unable to recognize YouTube streams. Grrrrr

Comment: I'd still like to know how to do this, but I've found a workaround. After looking through their older versions and not finding anything useful, I realized that I hadn't checked their nightlies to see if anything had been added/fixed. [Their git repo](http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win64/vlc-2.1.0-20120713-0403/) has v2.1.0, which seems to save recordings in __.mkv__ format. This works out for me.